# Why do some transaction on BSC not have a [Txn Fee] of 0?

Tags: web3js, bsc, fees

One transaction every block has a [Txn Fee] of `zero`. Relevant call to produce:

> webThree.eth.getTransaction('0x17247521041a79b7cbad3fc19d04f02ff1dd58488b85aaf6df514c31c2c03143').then(console.log)

Every block has one? Why even?

So that call fails once **every** block for this particular type of transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction fee of Zero means that the miners got paid in other ways to include that transaction in the blockchain. The amount paid can be in anything  (fiat, crypto, tokens, bitcoin, ...).

this method of paying miners is better than the usual gas payment for reasons of front-running, where other transactions can jump on top of your transaction and alter prices in their favor before your transaction gets processed.

There are services like Gas station network that offer these services.

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/104048/25049